# Why do I have to remove the CMOS battery each time I start the computer?

Tags: motherboard, bios, troubleshooting, cmos

Yesterday I replaced my CMOS battery with a new one. After that I turned on my PC, then my cooling fans and hard drive started up, but my monitor wasn't showed anything, only a blinking monitor indicator light. Then I removed my CMOS battery again and put it 15 minutes later. Then my cooling fans started faster (at that time monitor wasn't showed anything) and automatically turned off around 5 seconds later and it auto started, so then I got a display showing on my monitor. Then I had to press F2 to continue. I didn't know what it said because my BIOS language changed into Korean.

After my PC loaded Windows I restarted my PC again. Then again that problem reappeared. So I again did that same method, removed the CMOS battery and put it back in after 15 minutes. I have to do this method each time I start my PC. How to fix this?

when I start Windows my antivirus program says I have RootKit virus. To remove that I have to restart my PC, but I can't restart my PC because I have the above problem. Is there a connection between those?

Comment: the new CMOS battery is dead

Comment: @Keltari I tried with a another bt one same problem

Comment: when I start my windows my antivirus guard says I have *RootKit virus* . To remove that I want to restart my PC I can't Restart my Pc because I have the above problem. Is there a connection between those.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to clear CMOS with Jumper usually near the battery. you can find detailed information on your motherboard manual for clearing CMOS.